# Parsing quoted string only works in some cases

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've encountered something weird when trying to parse simple quoted strings.
So I've written this simple parser that successfully parses quoted strings like `"string"` or `""`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"

namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace iso8859 = boost::spirit::iso8859_1;


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    using namespace qi;

    std::string input = "\"\"";

    std::string::const_iterator front = input.cbegin();
    std::string::const_iterator end   = input.cend();
    bool parseSuccess = phrase_parse( front, end,
                                      '\"' >> *~char_('\"') >> '\"',
                                      iso8859::space );

    if ( front != end )
    {
        std::string trail( front, end );
        std::cout << "String parsing trail: " << trail << std::endl;
    }

    if ( !parseSuccess )
        std::cout << "Error parsing input string" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press enter to exit" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This all works perfectly fine, but when I extend the parsing rules to also parse things before the quoted string, it suddenly breaks..

So, of example, this parses successfully:

`std::string input = "normalString 10.0 1.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0"`
With parsing rule:

`*char_ >> *double_`

And now if I combine this rule with the quoted string rule:

`std::string input = "normalString 10.0 1.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 \"quotedString\""`

With parsing rule:

`*char_ >> *double_ >> '\"' >> *~char_('\"') >> '\"'`

It suddenly doesn't work anymore and parsing fails. I have no idea why. Can anyone explain this?

EDIT: Just in case it matters, I'm using Boost 1.53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **cv_and_he** stated earlier - your `*char_` eats everything and from the **"updated"** parser sequence you can guess why it did not work :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"

namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace iso8859 = boost::spirit::iso8859_1;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    using namespace qi;

    std::vector< std::string > inputVec{
        "normalString 10.0 1.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 \"quotedString\"",
        "normalString \"quotedString\"",
        "10.0 1.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 \"quotedString\"",
        "10.0 1.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 \"\"",
        "\"\""};

    for( const auto &input : inputVec )
    {
        std::string::const_iterator front = input.cbegin();
        std::string::const_iterator end   = input.cend();
        bool parseSuccess = phrase_parse( front, end,
            no_skip [ *(char_ - space - double_ - '\"') ] 
            >> *double_ >> '\"' >> *~char_('\"') >> '\"',
          iso8859::space );    
        if ( parseSuccess && front == end)
            std::cout << "success:";
        else
            std::cout << "failure:";
         std::cout << "`" << input << "`" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=837d43cf612b8f47a3a05698056ffc5c-e7fd08290543cba3074dbc20a85c5c10) are the two cases mentioned in the question using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG. You can clearly see that `*char_` consumes the whole string. In the first case `*double_` suceeds with an empty attribute since it matches 0 doubles. In the second case everything works the same until the literal `'"'` fails.

Comment: Assuming that the string that you want to parse is a standard identifier, I think that the cleanest way to solve this problem would be: `lexeme[alpha >> *alnum] >> *double_ >> '"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"';`. If you are using rules as in the example linked above, you can even omit the `lexeme` if you remove the skipper from your rule: `rule<std::string::const_iterator,std::string()> string_rule = alpha >> *alnum;`.

Comment: @cv_and_he - as for adding extra rule - fully agreed. I think it's good to know both ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is clearer to me now. I thought because I defined a double_ parser after the *char_ spirit would automatically parse all the numbers with the double_ parser, but apparently I was wrong.. @cv_and_he Thanks for the debug example. I didn't even know you could do that :)

Comment: You are welcome. Coincidentally I ran into similar `issue` a few days ago :-)